# Footer Row Grid VIew

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have  footer row in the in Grid View to add the new record. In footer i have three columns (name, phone no & address. When user enters phone no, corresponding details needs to be fetched & bind it to other items in the Footer rows

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ShowFooter="true" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
     </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
     </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I don't have any idea how i can achieve the same. Can I call web service or use jquery for the same

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this..

ASP:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'</asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" autopostback="true" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox> //added code here
   </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code Behind

```
protected void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code here call back fields to other textboxes
}
```

This hasn't been tested but I have used the onTextChanged before.. just maybe not in a gridivew.. you might need to use..

```
Textbox txtPhone = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhone");
```

to find the controls in the footer. Once you find the controls you should be able to populate your textbox with sqldataadapter or datareader.

HOpe this puts you in the right direction!

Comment: No, as soon as focus is lost on the txtName, the txtName_TextChanged will fire and do whatever you tell it to do in the method.

Comment: Text changed event is fired for normal Textbox . This also causes page post back, which causes unnecessary round trips. so want mechanism which will bind asynchronise way

Comment: You can use an UpdatePanel. That way it's asynchronous. You will need to put the entire gridview inside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Putting GridView in update panel will be  better idea. However entire grid will be posted to the server. Can I use json & web method for the same? I don't have any idea how to bind GridView footer through  json objects

Comment: No idea man. Update panel is the route I have gone and will probably continue to go.